# Unable to save column in flexible tables (grids) in the system configuration

Tags: admin, magento-2.1

In Magento admin Stores->Configuration->General->Contacts I have a flexible table (grid) similar like this one here:

http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-guide-to-create-table-setting-in-the-system-configuration

Everything was working fine and all data was stored, until I try to save country.

I am trying to get country with:

```
        $this->addColumn(
        'test', [
            'label' => __('Test'),
            'renderer' => $this->getTestRenderer(),
        ]
    );

protected function getTestRenderer() {
    if (!$this->_testRender) {
        $this->_testRender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Vendor\Namespace\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Test::class, '', ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
        );
    }
    return $this->_testRender;
}
```

It is working and returning the Magento country list with 2 characters ISO country code and label:

```
<option value="">--Please Select--</option><option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AX">Åland Islands</option><option value="AL">Albania</option><option value="DZ">Algeria</option><option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
```

After I select the country and I press the save config button in admin panel the page is refreshing and value is not save.
I found that the others dropdown that I have are created by using Indexed Array, not Associative Array.

I am using test for label and column name just for developing and already have column country, but I want to remove the input field and to use the dropdown for better consistency /for example you can type Germany,Deutschland and etc./.

Can you help me and tell me how to save the field?